# How to Update table By following image?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update my table like

**Relation A.id = B.a_id**
[image]

Comment: Not my downvote, but the downvote was most likely given because you didn't show any effort to solve your problem.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nope. Not me either,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL:

```
UPDATE B
JOIN A ON B.email = A.email
AND B.a_id = A.id
SET B.email = '';

UPDATE B
JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM B
    GROUP BY email, a_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS dp ON B.email = dp.email
AND B.a_id = dp.a_id
AND B.id != dp.id
SET B.email = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

The first case, when exist email in table A:

```
update table_b b set email = '' where (select 1 from table_a a where a.email = b.email) = 1;
```

Next case, when email duplicate in table B:

```
update table_b b set email = '' where b.id in 
(select
    bb.id
    from table_b bb
    where bb.email in (
        select bbb.email,count(*)
        from table_b bbb
        where bbb.email = b.email
        having count(*) > 1
    ) 
    limit 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `inner join` would do the trick

```
UPDATE TableB
SET EMAIL='' --or set this to null 
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB  ON
TableA.id = TableB.a_id AND
TableA.email = TableB.email
```

Where As for updating duplicates in the same Table i.e TableB i would opt for `CTE` and `Row_number`

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT id,a_id,email,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY a_id,email ORDER BY id)
   FROM TableB
)
UPDATE  CTE SET email='' WHERE RN > 1
```